Call a method in a bundle on Design Automation
The code to be included in the package and uploaded to DesignAutomation:
private void HandleDesignAutomationReadyEvent(object sender, DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs e)
{
    if (...) // The flag I'm getting from the API side.
    {
        Method1();
    }
    else 
    {
        Method2();
    }

}

The code which I have on the API side:
public async Task RunDesignAutomation()
{
   var workItem = new WorkItem()
   {
      ActivityId = activityName,
      Arguments = new Dictionary<string, IArgument>()
      {
          { "rvtFile",  inputFileArgument },
          { "inputJson",  inputJsonArgument },
          { "result",  outputFileArgument },
          { "onComplete", onCompleteArgument }
      }
   };
  
   _designAutomation.CreateWorkItemAsync(workItem);
}

How can I set my own flag for a WorkItem that will help determine on the bundle side which method to use? (Method1 or Method2)
Note: Method1 and Method2 accept a different 'inputJson'

I'd recommend that you add another argument that you can use to switch between the 2 methods.

Do you mean something like this?
Arguments = new Dictionary<string, IArgument>()
{
{ "rvtFile",  inputFileArgument },
{ "inputJson",  inputJsonArgument },
{ "result",  outputFileArgument },
{ "onComplete", onCompleteArgument },
{ "methodId", 1}
}

That will work - you may have to read up documentation on how to pass this as a raw text input. Or you can pass in the value to the new argument as a json argument similar to inputJson.
Alternatively you can chose to add the flag inside inputJson instead of creating a separate argument.

yes, good idea about inputJson, thank you
